# Getting a Blank Page after putting Typo3 on a Docker Container

Tags: docker, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to setup an existing Typo3-Projekt on a Docker container.

I get a blank site and the Errorlog says:

> Mon, 20 Jan 2020 16:00:12 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.ProductionExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1203699034: A cache with identifier "assets" does not exist. | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Exception\NoSuchCacheException thrown in file /var/www/html/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheManager.php in line 131.

The cache is already deleted.

Comment: I used the quote operator (>) to format your error, and cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the Docker Environment. Docker has a strange way setting the file permissions. Anyway, i recommend using [ddev](https://www.ddev.com/) for Local ENV.

Answer (score 0):

As usual:
get more information by enabling develop-mode in install-tool (Admin-Tools -> Settings) -> `Configuration Preset`. also enable a stacktrace by adding

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

to your typoscript.

Regarding assets:
if you copied an existing instance into docker, have you copied or cleared all temporary data?
In the Install-Tool (Admin-Tools -> Maintenance) : `Remove Temporary Assets`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

The problem is, i dont have access to the backend anymore.
I deleted all files inside the /typo3temp after moving to the Docker Container.

Comment: If you can't access the TYPO3 backend you stay with the install tool: just call `yourdomain/typo3/install`, before create the file `typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL`

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem in ddev 1.13.0 and the only way to solve it for me, was upgrading ddev to 1.13.1

[image: Error Message "Cache with identifier does not exist"]

To upgrade ddev, you can simply execute:
`brew upgrade ddev`

Keep in mind that all projects have to be updated as well by simply running `ddev config` again for this projects.